# Issue with Chrome extension in ReactJS Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux-form

In my project, I am using Redux Form. I have Grammarly Chrome extension. There is textarea Field in my Form. When I Click on Textarea field the textarea field disappears and it appears on the side. If I change textarea field to text its working fine but I need textarea here. I post the screenshot for a better understanding of the problem. There is any way to overcome this problem.

Before clicking on textarea, the textarea display normally.

[image]

After Clicking on textarea, the textarea box appears on right side of the other fields.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Grammarly extension set inline styles for the `textarea`/`contenteditable` fields.

You need just check which styles are overwritten by extension and then just fix them by applying your styles.

Also, you can disable initialization of Grammarly extension by special attribute: `data-enable-grammarly="false."`

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/616#issuecomment-343596615).